# Implicit function theorem: solving equation for a variable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, implicit-function-theorem

I have a question about the implicit function theorem. I have one equation with 3 variables and I have to know if we can solve the equation uniquely for $y$. But I don't know when that is allowed and how I can do it.

It is about this equation:
$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} -  \cos(z) = 0$$
in a neighborhood of $(0,1,0)$.

Comment: Hi. are you familiar with what the implicit function theorem says in general?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem

Answer (score 3):

When you have a single equation,
$$ f(x,y,z) = 0,$$
the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) is fairly straightforward to apply. (Here, we're assuming that $f$ is continuously differentiable.)

Suppose that the point $(a,b,c)$ obeys $f(a,b,c) = 0 $, and suppose we want to prove that there exists a continuously differentiable function $g(x,z)$, defined on a neighbourhood of $(a,c)$, such that $g(a,c) = b$, and such that $$f(x,g(x,z),z) = 0.$$

By the implicit function theorem, all we have to do is show that
$$ \frac {\partial f}{\partial y}(a,b,c) \neq 0.$$

So in your case, we apply this with $f(x,y,z) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} - \cos z$ and $(a,b,c) = (0,1,0)$.

Anyway, in this example, it's not hard to solve for $g(x,z)$ directly: I believe the answer is
$$ g(x,z) = + \sqrt{\cos^2 z - x^2 - z^2},$$
valid on an open neighbourhood of $(0,1,0)$ chosen to be small enough such that the expression inside the square root is positive throughout this neighbourhood.